# Setting up a variable variable of a variable in a array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Apologies for the title but i hope it makes sense.

I am trying to assign a item number [based on number of loops run] based in a array. I really hope that makes sense.

```
    //declare variables
    int[] listToSort;
    int listSize, minIndex, min, tmp, item;
    int randNum;

    //create scanner
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    //ask user first question
    System.out.println("Size of list to sort?");
    //set first question answer to variable "listSize"
    listSize = myScanner.nextInt();

    //Create array size based on the answer of the first question
    listToSort = new int[listSize];

    //Repeat loop
    for (int i = 0; i < listToSort.length; i++){
        //Generate random number between 0 - 100
        randNum = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * (100 - 1 + 1));
        //Set array to random number
        listToSort[i] = randNum;
}

        int pass = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < listToSort.length;){
            minIndex = pass;
            //set min to item "pass" of "listToSort"
            ????????????
```

I have been given some Scribble psudo code to assist me but still no luck. Hopefully someone can make it a bit clearer for me.

[image]

Appreciate the help guys

Comment: No idea what this question is about.

Comment: My apologies if i have not explained it as clearly as it should have been @jelinson.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting picture :).

I think "set min to item "pass" of "listToSort" basically means:

`min=listToSort[pass]`

Comment: Thanks for that @Alvin. Ill give it a go and see where it ends up. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Friendly suggestion though, it looks like you are trying to implement selection sort? It may be worthwhile to understand the actual algorithm before coding. Like, can you describe the algorithm that the pseudo presents in plain English?

Comment: Yes you are correct @Alvin. To answer your question the logic does make sense to me. Essentially the pseudo code is asking the user for a array size, which it will then loop through assigning each item a index if the item is between the argument defined. Does that sound about right? I know i have just summered it quite basically but im sure that is the main purpose of the program.

p.s - The "replace" line has now stumped me. what is the syntax for replacing ints with ints?

Comment: What if I tell you "replace" and "set" mean the same thing? The main purpose of the program is to sort an array by using selection sort. Imagine you have deck of 13 cards of a suite in random order (say Ace to King of Club). How would you lay down the cards on a table in sorted order?